Google docs на андроид не отображает Устройство на начальной странице приложения
Ранее, при открытии приложения Google docs на андроид, было две вкладки с документами: Диск и Устройство телефона. Теперь отображается только Диск.
КАК ВЕРНУТЬ ВКЛАДКУ УСТРОЙСТВО на главную страницу? Также, раннее при создании копии файла был предоставлен выбор: сохранить на Google диск, либо на Устройство. Теперь есть только Диск (пример есть на скрине).
Вкладка Устройства в приложении исчезла после перемещения документов через Проводник в другую папку.



добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать отдельными вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Возможно, у вас изменились права пользователя, либо у проводника нет разрешения на чтение этой папки.

Справа вверху на главной нажмете иконку "папка" и будет там "Устройство телефона". Переделал Google приложение, как раньше уже не будет.

Кстати, есть хорошие  опенсурсные аналоги, похожие на классический стиль, с возможностью ручного добавления входных точек.

Аналог, предложенный вами мне подходит. Благодарю
